# To what distribution it's similar? Looks like an exponential but it's not

Tags: exponential-distribution, density-estimation, distribution-identification

To what distribution it's similar? Looks like an exponential but it's not.

It's seems to have a property, that if I zoom it (`xlim`) then each time it has the same shape. [some "fractal kind" property].

It doesn't fit to Exponential Distribution.

It can be observed on the below plots:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a distribution with positive values only, generally decreasing, and a long tail. You might want to start with Pareto or power law distributions.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403532/can-kernel-density-estimation-estimate-an-exponential-distribution

Comment: It's not likely to be especially close to any simple distribution; however, some may be adequate. Are the data integers? The spikes at round numbers present smoe interesting problems (with rounder numbers seeming to get bigger spikes).

Comment: @Glen_b, the date is not integers, but peaks about 50 and 100 make sense.

Comment: It may be helpful to indicate why it does.

Comment: I assume the data might be related to prices. And for prices, sometimes, there increased likelihood to integers (like 50\$, 100\$, etc...)

Comment: @B.Liu , I acutally figured, that the Pareto distribution makes a very nice fit.
But(!), for each part of X sclale the $\alpha$ should be different.
  For example for X$\in$ [1, 100] -> $\alpha$= 0.5,
                     when X$\in$ [101, 1000] ->$\alpha$= 0.9,
                     and when X$\in$ [1001, 01000] -> $\alpha$= 1.3,

    Is there is something like piece-wise Pareto, where each "piece" has a different alpha?